# How can I use Google Drive API to scan a document in an Android Studio app?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-api, ocr, scanning

I'm trying to build a simple Android Studio app that can read text from images: the idea is to use the camera to take a picture of a single document page and then do some OCR.
I've already tried to use my OCR on documents that I scanned manually with the Google Drive app and the result is satisfying, but when I try with raw pictures from the camera, it doesn't work anymore.
1) Is there a way to use Google Drive API (or similar) to obtain a good quality scan from the camera without reinventing the wheel?
2) Also, is there a way to do the whole process from the camera to the final text with known tools?
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused by your question as Google Drive API is just for storage/read/write documents and isn't related to OCR. Are you thinking about MLKit: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition ?

Comment: @MorrisonChang My app has 2 parts: first, take a picture and produce an image which is good enough to do OCR, and then do OCR. In the question, I'm saying that the camera alone (without some additional processing) doesn't suffice for the first step, whereas the scanning function of the Google Drive app does (with the same OCR tool). The OCR comes later, but I need an image which is "good enough" to make OCR feasible

Comment: @I'mD. Did you ever figure this one out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use an Intent in your app to use the camera and resources from the google drive, it's like a link that drives the user to an other app that makes the hard work, like camera resources or google drive or even the google lens. You Can search more and find the solution for your specific problem in those links. https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary

Comment: I still don't see how this explains how to launch into Google Drive specifically to use their scanning and image enhancement features. Is this supposed to explain this ? Because that GitHub is for a 3rd party app and I don't see usage of google drive.